# Does Vercel has any features to moniter static asset response time?

Tags: next.js, amazon-cloudwatch, vercel

I'm currently subscribing Vercel's Pro plan.

Before opening my service, I wanna add notification system which monitering system which watches my vercel project(made with Next.js) server response time.

Comparing with AWS, It would be similar with AWS CloudWatch alerting TargetResponseTime.

Is there any way I could acheive this with Vercel??